# How to avoid the "Application Android keyboard is not responding" message?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Sometimes, when I start an app in the emulator, I see the dialog alert showing the:

`Application Android Keyboard (in process com.android.inputmethod.latin) is not responding`.

I know that if I click `Force close` I can continue or if I click `Wait`, after a short time, I can work. But I would like to know if there is a way to avoid this (useless) message to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that the standard android keyboard needs quite a lot of memory. Try increasing the available memory for the emulator.

Comment: Sorry, how can emulator memory be increased?

Comment: You will need to create a new AVD but you can find the instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html#AVDCmdLine)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problems for years now. In my case the problem particularly appears if I don't restart the emulator but load another application. I read a lot how this problem can be resolved, but I couldn't found a solution. So my suggestion is: don't worry and don't spend too much time on this.